# With MVC3, how can I change the controller/action based on the "accept" header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, http-headers

I have an application that is going to act as a "catch-all" for requests that could be coming from a variety of targets.  I would like to be able to redirect to a different controller/action in my application based on the value of the "accept" header.

Clarification: I would like to do this without an HTTP Handler, if possible.

Comment: yes, the request will always be for the root - "/"; but if the "Accept" header is "json", the Route should be /home/json; if the header is "xml", the result should be /home/xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    {

    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var accept = httpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"];
        if (string.Equals("xml", accept, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            rd.Values["action"] = "xml";
        }
        else if (string.Equals("json", accept, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            rd.Values["action"] = "json";
        }
        return rd;
    }
}
```

and then register this route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(
        "Default", 
        new MyRoute(
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        )
    );
}
```

Now when you POST to `/home` and set the `Accept` request header to `xml` the `Xml` action of the `Home` controller will be hit.

Answer (score 0):

make a route.. just a simple class and derive it from `RouteBase` here you will find the method `GetRouteData(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)` with return type of `RouteData`
u can pick out the headers of your choice from the `httpcontext` and add the values of ur route to the return value of the function..

Answer (score 0):

you can use Phil haack [Route Magic](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx) plugin it has [HttpHandler Routing](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/04/routehandler-for-http-handlers.aspx) but it use HttpHandler you can take a look , see if you like it

[Route Magic](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx)