# Cleanest way to model bind Accept header in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I'm implementing a REST layer in .NET MVC 3.  I'm looking for a clean way to grab the Accept header to determine if I should return Json or Xml.

I would also like to be able to spoof this header with a GET parameter for debugging (I want this to persist to prod too).

Here's how I'm currently detecting this:

```
if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json") || Request.Url.Query.Contains("application/json"))
```

This is the only place in my controller code that touches the Request object directly.  I would like a cleaner, more testable way to read this.  My ideal solution would be a parameter on the controller.

I tried several keywords to see if the default model binder would pick up on it, but nothing I tried worked.

**So what's the cleanest way to get this information?  A custom model binder?  Can you provide an example?**

Comment: If you aren't opposed to mvc4 webapi you can have this handled for you. Not to mention when you migrate your app to mvc4+ at some point in the future you will be cust handling something MVC already does for you. Search mvc4 content type negotiation for more info.

Comment: I've noticed this and am very excited about it, but unfortunately I can't deliver this project under an RC, and from what I can tell there is no release date for 4.

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/returning_data_view_from_controller_action

Comment: @Mark, this is similar to what I'm doing now with a base controller and a couple helpers which access the Request object.

Comment: You specifically asked for model binding, but you may consider creating a custom route object. Override the GetRouteData wherein you can inspect the accept header and set the action method name that should execute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096605/with-mvc3-how-can-i-change-the-controller-action-based-on-the-accept-header

Comment: This project has been shipped for a while now, but thanks for the suggestion.  It's a good one.  I'm looking at the Web API for the next project though--installing VS2012 today!  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An action filter attribute would be a good, clean solution.

There's a good tutorial here : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I understand this correctly, I'll need to duplicate every action--one for Xml and one for Json.  That seems a bit excessive just for encapsulation and testability.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can register it as a global action filter and have both the Xml and Json handled in the one filter.. is that not what you're after? You'll still need to store it in the ViewData/Bag which isn't as "clean" I guess..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing any better alternatives to a custom model binder.  I'll post my implementation of the binder here in case anyone else sees this.  Using a model binder allows the Accept header to be strongly bound to a direct input on the action, allowing for direct testing of the return types and doesn't force you to artificially have more actions than you need, nor result to the dynamic typed viewdata/bag.

Here's the Model Binder with a supporting enum type:

```
public enum RequestAcceptType
{
    NotSpecified,
    Json,
    Xml
}

public class RequestAcceptTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }

        RequestAcceptType acceptType = RequestAcceptType.NotSpecified;

        // Try for Json
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json") || controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            acceptType = RequestAcceptType.Json;
        }

        // Default to Xml
        if (acceptType == RequestAcceptType.NotSpecified)
        {
            acceptType = RequestAcceptType.Xml;
        }

        return acceptType;
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant bit in Global.asax in the Application_Start method:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(RequestAcceptType)] = new RequestAcceptTypeModelBinder();
```

Then to use it in your actions, just make an argument (any name) with the enum type:

```
public ActionResult Index(RequestAcceptType acceptType)
```

If nobody responds with a better method in a couple days, I'll accept this as the answer.